# iOS: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios

Apple keeps sending me the same error:

`Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.`

I've been trying to submit my app to the app store but it keeps getting rejected. I've looked at all the other SO questions/answers but I can't seem to get it to work even though I keep regenerating the provisioning profile. I am not even using push notifications at all.

Not using push:

[image]

Generating my profile called Coaster Profile

[image]

And using that profile when submitting to the app store:

[image]

I even tried adding the DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS variable:

[image]

But nothing is working. I never even used push notifications. Please help!! I'm using xcode + objective c

Comment: Most likley the key is "Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service" so look for any usage you have, perhaps ina 3rd party library you are including in your project.

Comment: I'm only using iad and admob

Comment: Are you using Cordova (PhoneGap) for this app?

Comment: nope just plain old xcode + objective c