# Xcode: Where is the Entitlements.plist file?

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements

I'm trying to submit my first app but it apple keeps giving me an email about `Missing Push Notification Entitlement` (asked a question here: [iOS: Missing Push Notification Entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542578/ios-missing-push-notification-entitlement))

This guy here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681454/1555312 seems to have an answer, which is to remove the Entitlements.plist file. However, I don't know where this file is. Could you let me know how to 1) locate the file 2) delete it 3) regenerate it?

Comment: see this link may be helps with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217716/how-to-locate-the-entitlements-plist-file-in-an-xcode-6-3-ios-project

Answer (score 6):

You can add entitlement from Project Target.

[image: http://imgur.com/BPwPGc8]

you project *Target* -> *Capabilities* ->*Background Mode*-> *ON*-> select checkbox for *Remote notifications*

Comment: Note in Xcode 11.3 (and some earlier versions) the tab is "Signing & Capabilities" and capabilities are added using "+ Capability" at the top left corner of the tab subwindow instead of via the on/off switches.

Answer (score 1):

When we are using push notifications related code in our app and if that capability is not configured in Xcode or in App ID that mail comes from apple. If you are not going to use Push notifications in your app, then you can ignore that mail. But if you are using it, enable that capability in Xcode-> Target--> Capabilities --> Push Notifications

or

Go to developer portal and check enable push notifications capability for your App ID and enable it if it's disabled.